# Progress 4GL - Define variable month/year

Tags: date, range, progress-4gl, 4gl

Here's the problem, i need to create a date range on the variable below.

```
    define variable s_date as character format "99/9999" no-undo.
```

There is a start_date column in my db (format "99/99/9999"(dd/mm/yyyy)) the date when a customer sales order was entered.

What i need to do is set the variable to create the date range, search and display the results of every sales order of the defined month and year.

PS: I 'm using a form , so the user can define the range of the month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started. You will have to look into converting it to fit your form.

If you're on an older release that haven't got the ADD-INTERVAL function you can use the DATE function and add +1 to the month instead (just remember that if the month is December (12) you're going to have to increase the year instead and set the month to 1).

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFromDate  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dtFromDate AS DATE        NO-UNDO LABEL "From".
DEFINE VARIABLE dtTomDate  AS DATE        NO-UNDO LABEL "Tom".


DEFINE VARIABLE iMonth     AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iYear      AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.



UPDATE cFromDate FORMAT "99/9999" NO-ERROR.

IF LENGTH(cFromDate) <> 6 THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Invalid format" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
    RETURN ERROR.
END.

ASSIGN
    iMonth = INTEGER(SUBSTRING(cFromDate,1,2)) 
    iYear  = INTEGER(SUBSTRING(cFromDate,3,4)) NO-ERROR.

IF iMonth < 1 OR iMonth > 12 THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Invalid month" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
    RETURN ERROR.
END.

IF iYear < 1990 OR iYear > 2020 THEN DO:
    MESSAGE "Invalid year" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX ERROR.
    RETURN ERROR.
END.

ASSIGN
    dtFromDate = DATE(iMonth, 1, iYear)
    dtTomDate  = ADD-INTERVAL(dtFromDate, 1, "month") - 1.


DISPLAY 
    dtFromDate FORMAT "9999-99-99"
    dtTomDate  FORMAT "9999-99-99".
```